# How to get the database in SQL script that is stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I wrote a program in its SQL database is stored procedures . I want the get whole database with stored procedures script . I would when the page is loaded if the database to be removed was created . I made generate script the SQL script in the folder bin.
But was error.
The code in vb.net

```
Dim cn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True")  'Connect To Database
Dim myconnection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=amlak;Integrated Security=True")
Try
        myconnection.Open()
        myconnection.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

        Dim strsql As String = "CREATE DATABASE amlak COLLATE Persian_100_CI_AS"
        Dim cmd2 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strsql, cn)
        cn.Open()
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = cn
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader("script.sql")
        cmd.CommandText = objReader.ReadToEnd
        cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText.Replace("GO", ";")
        cmd.CommandText.Split(";")
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cn.Close()
        Application.Restart()
    End Try
```

stored procedures was an error .

> CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.
>
> A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'procedure'.
>
> The variable name '@cod' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
> A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'procedure'.
>
> The variable name '@cod' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.
>
> A RETURN statement with a return value cannot be used in this context.

Comment: What error message are you seeing? What line does it occur at?

Comment: Most of those error messages are very straight forward and self explanatory. Have you tried googling them?

Answer (score 0):

If it is really a storedprocedure then I think you do not need to use StreamReader.  You just need to know the name of the stored procedure to call and set it as the CommandText.

```
cmd.CommandText = "the name of your stored procedure"
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
cmd.Connection = cn
cn.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
cn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replacing GO with ; will not work. 
You will have to execute every command separately. 
Please note that the result of the split operation is an array. As you do not assign the result to a variable, this line does not do anything helpful

```
cmd.CommandText.Split(";")
```

Also: replacing GO with ; is only a good idea if you are sure that there are no other instances of GO in your script.
I would recommend you do something like this:

```
  Dim cmds As String = File.ReadAllText(pFilename)
  Dim queries As String() 
  queries = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(cmds, "^GO\s+$", RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Multiline Or RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
  For Each curQuery In queries
    cmd.CommandText = curQuery
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
  Next
```